# Why static memory not showing Polymorphism?

Tags: c++, dynamic, polymorphism

I have made two simple classes of Polygon and Triangle. (Triangle is inheriting from Polygon and both have virtual Draw() function)

Calling code is simple:

```
 void main()
    {

        Polygon *p_t = new Triangle();

        Polygon p_tStatic;
        Triangle t;

        p_tStatic = t;

        cout<<"Calling Dynamic Allocated Memory's Draw():"<<endl;
        p_t->Draw();

        cout<<"Calling Static Allocated Memory's Draw():"<<endl;
        p_tStatic.Draw();

        _getch();
    }
```

Output is:

[image: Output]

I know many will think it as less Researched and naive sort of question, but all I want to know is why it's showing Non-Polymorphic behaviour in latter case. Why can't we do it for Static Memory?

Comment: Are you asking why the C++ language is designed in this way?

Comment: Why doesn't it allows us?

Comment: Runtime polymorphism has an overhead, and the language does not force you to incur it. The semantics of your code are that you are calling a `Polygon` member on a `Polygon` object. `p_tStatic` doesn't know anything about triangles.

Comment: Check out the "Law of Three", what you do is slicing an object during initialization. The lookup is still dynamic, only the actual (dynamic and static) type is not what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about two phases of the program; first the compilation and then the run-time, in the case when you do not declare your variable as a reference or as a pointer, its type is already decided during the compilation time as `Polygon`, and its member function is called. To benefit from dynamic binding which happens during the run-time (when you actually run the program), you need to call your object either through a pointer or a reference.

Answer (score 2):

`p_tStatic` is, and will always be, a `Polygon`. It is not a `Triangle`.

Objects cannot change type after they have been constructed.

Answer (score 1):

As above answers point out, an object created from static memory can never change its type; be it compile or run time. A triangle is a polygon so polygon gets only that part of the triangle which fits into a polygon (i.e. Object Slicing) and hence we can't perform polymorphism on runtime